# Special characters (backslash) in .properties-file

Tags: java, properties-file

I have several backslashes ("\") in a properties file. This is what the file looks like:

```
dir=\\127.0.0.1\d$\dir\dir2\dir3
```

This results in the string `127.0.0.1d$dirdir2dir3` when the property `dir` is used in the code.

I have tried unicode escapes like this:

```
dir=\u005C\u005C127.0.0.1\u005Cd$\u005Cdir\u005Cdir2\u005Cdir3
```

I have also tried backslash as escape like this:

```
dir=\\\\127.0.0.1\\d$\\dir\\dir2\\dir3
```

Both of the tries above results in the string `\\127.0.0.1d$dirdir2dir3` when the property `dir` is used in the code.

I want the property `dir` to be set to `\\127.0.0.1\d$\dir\dir2\dir3` when the property is used in the code. What shall the .properties-file look like to get this result?

Comment: @Tunaki I have edited my post. Is it possible to use Properties.load() when the properties are read using annotation?

Comment: Oh that is a very different question, because I assume you're using Spring behind this to inject the value. You should ask a new question with your Spring config instead of editing this one, but make sure you read this question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858207/backslash-in-proprties-file-is-being-ignored-by-springs-environment-vari.

Comment: @Tunaki Ok. I have asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828523/special-characters-in-properties-file