# Special characters ("\") in .properties-file

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I'm developing a Java application that executes on Windows. I have several backslashes ("\") in a .properties-file. This is what the file looks like:

```
dir=\\127.0.0.1\d$\dir\dir2\dir3
```

I read the property `dir` using `Spring` annotation `Value`:

```
@Value("${dir}")
protected String dir;
```

This results in the string `127.0.0.1d$dirdir2dir3` when the property `dir` is used in the code.

I have tried unicode escapes like this:

```
dir=\u005C\u005C127.0.0.1\u005Cd$\u005Cdir\u005Cdir2\u005Cdir3
```

I have also tried backslash as escape like this:

```
dir=\\\\127.0.0.1\\d$\\dir\\dir2\\dir3
```

Both of the tries above results in the string `\\127.0.0.1d$dirdir2dir3` when the property `dir` is used in the code.

I want the property `dir` to be set to `\\127.0.0.1\d$\dir\dir2\dir3` when the property is used in the code. What shall the .properties-file look like to get this result?

Comment: Have you tried the single quote ?

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux Yes. It will result in '127.0.0.1d$dirdir2dir3'.

Comment: Use forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forward slashes, beyond reason it works on Windows

Answer (score -1):

The backslash escape is meant for compiler to understand that the next character is valid and store the result in a `String`. When you type `\\127.0.0.1\d$\dir\dir2\dir3`, all the backslashes are escaped except the second one (obviously). Do not use a `String` object here. Try with `Properties` and post your results. I had the same experience and use of Properties worked fine.

Comment: This is a properties file. The compiler never comes anywhere near it.

Comment: The JVM also. When it encounters backslash it escapes the backslash and add next character to the `String`